# Wordpress - How to save multiple select item value from metabox

Tags: wordpress, save, meta-boxes

I did a metabox that contains a multiple select item that takes his values from a custom post type.
It works but i'm unable to save it...can you help me?

```
function conduce_palinsesto($post){
?><p>Seleziona il/i conduttore/i</p>
<p>Tieni premuto CTRL per selezionare più conduttori</p>
<?php
global $post;
echo '<select name="conduce[]" id="conduce" multiple="yes">';
$val = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'speaker', true);
$q = get_posts('post_type=speaker');

foreach ($q as $obj)
{
    echo '<option value="'.$obj->ID.'" "checked="checked">'.$obj->post_title.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
}
```

This is my save function...that don't work.

```
add_action('save_post', 'rb_speaker_save_details');
function rb_speaker_save_details($post_id)
{
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
  return $post_id;
} else {
  $speak = implode(',', $_POST['conduce']);
  update_post_meta($post_id, 'conduce', speak);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's probably been long solved but here is the answer. I was having the same problem and this is how I solved it.

to save

```
function rb_speaker_save_details($post_id) {

$is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
$is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
$is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'name_of_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'name_of_nonce' ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) ? 'true' : 'false';

if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ) {
    return;
}

if( isset($_POST['conduce']) ) {
  $speak = implode(',', $_POST['conduce']);
  update_post_meta($post_id, 'conduce', $speak);
}}
```

and to check the option based on the saved data

```
            echo '<option value="', $slug, '" ';
        if(strpos($conduce_val, $slug) !==false) { echo 'selected="selected"'; }
        echo '>',the_title(), "</option>\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

For saving data inserted/selected in a metabox you have to use the [save_post action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post). Maybe you want to have a look at the [metabox example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) in the WP codex.

Comment: i added the save function

Comment: Is it correct, that the custom meta name is "conduce" in the save function an "speaker" in the metabox function?

Comment: speaker is the post type slug

Comment: But in line 7 in your snippet your get the post meta "speaker". I think it has to be "conduce", hasn't it?

Comment: in that line i take posts from another post-type as options

Comment: [link*(http://pastebin.com/Ap1VNzcm) here there is the complete file if you want check it

Comment: Okay I found two bugs:
1. in the pastebin in line 121 it has to be `$post_id` instead of `$id`
2. you cannot use `esc_attr` in line 121 on an array
I hope this helps!